# Unity 2d_ Constant Player movement along the x axis

Tags: unity, movement

The movement of my player depends on swipes,

swipe left-> character moves to the left

swipe right-> character moves to the right

right now i am only getting a small movement, meaning that the player moves along the X axis but it stops inmediatelly. This is the code i have to check the swipes direction:

PLayer.cs:

```
public Vector2 desiredPosition;

void Update()
{
    if (MobileInput.Instance.SwipeIzquierda)
    {
        desiredPosition += Vector2.left; 
    }
    if (MobileInput.Instance.SwipeDerecha)
    {
        desiredPosition += Vector2.right;
    }

    transform.position. = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, desiredPosition, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

In the MobileInput script i control the swipes:

```
private const float DEADZONE = 100.0f;
public static MobileInput Instance { set; get; }
private bool swipeIzquierda, swipeDerecha, swipeAbajo, swipeArriba;
private Vector2 swipePuntoAhora, touchComienzo;

public bool SwipeIzquierda { get { return swipeIzquierda; } }
public bool SwipeDerecha { get { return swipeDerecha; } }
public bool SwipeArriba { get { return swipeArriba; } }
public bool SwipeAbajo { get { return swipeAbajo; } }

private void Awake()
{
    Instance = this;
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
private void Update () {

    Debug.Log(SwipeIzquierda);


    swipeDerecha = swipeIzquierda = false;

    #region Input Pc
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        touchComienzo = Input.mousePosition;
    }
    else if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        touchComienzo = swipePuntoAhora = Vector2.zero;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Mobile Input
    if (Input.touches.Length != 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("hola");
        if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            touchComienzo = Input.mousePosition;
        }

        else if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Ended || Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)
        {
            touchComienzo = swipePuntoAhora = Vector2.zero;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Calcular distancia

    swipePuntoAhora = Vector2.zero;
    if (touchComienzo != Vector2.zero)
    {
        //Mobile
        if (Input.touches.Length != 0)
        {
            swipePuntoAhora = Input.touches[0].position - touchComienzo;
        }
        //PC
        else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            swipePuntoAhora = (Vector2)Input.mousePosition - touchComienzo;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Calcular DEadzone del swipe

    if (swipePuntoAhora.magnitude > DEADZONE)
    {
        float x = swipePuntoAhora.x;
        float y = swipePuntoAhora.y;

        if (Mathf.Abs(x) > Mathf.Abs(y))
        {
            //Izquierda o Derecha
            if (x < 0)
            {
                swipeIzquierda = true;
            }
            else
            {
                swipeDerecha = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Arriba o Abajo
            if (y < 0)
            {
                swipeAbajo = true;
            }
            else
            {
                swipeArriba = true;
            }

        }

        touchComienzo = swipePuntoAhora = Vector2.zero;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The goal of all of this is to:

If i swipe to te right, the player starts to walk to the right AND continues doing so unless i swipe to the left, only then the player starts to move to the left. I want the movement to be constant in one direction until the other swipe changes it

Any help with this will be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
public Vector2 desiredPosition;

void Update()
{
    string dir;
    if (MobileInput.Instance.SwipeIzquierda)
    {
        dir = "left"; 
    }
    if (MobileInput.Instance.SwipeDerecha)
    {
        dir = "right";
    }
    if (dir == "left")
    {
        desiredPosition += Vector2.left; 
    }
    if (dir == "right")
    {
        desiredPosition += Vector2.right;
    }

    transform.position. = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, desiredPosition, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

This will change `dir` to either left or right, and then later in the update it will move either left or right. This means that you first check to see if the direction has changed (or set it for the first time), and then you move along that direction. I wouldn't personally use Vector2.MoveTowards for the movement along an axis, but this will solve your problem.